# escape special character in progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've found very strange action in filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader

```
<style>
 .some{ width: 16px; height: 16px;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="C:/Users/usr7/Desktop/(x86)/close.png", sizingMethod='scale');
 }
</style>

<div class='some'>
 hello
</div>
```

If AlphaImageLoader' src has brace character that is ( ) , It don't work at ie8 and ie9.
Is there any method to escape brace characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use escaping for special chars inside CSS string tokens, i.e. replace the parentheses symbols with `\29` and `\28` (which represent left and right parentheses, accordingly).

#### Concrete Example

```css
src="C:/Users/usr7/Desktop/\29x86\28/close.png"
```

#### References

- [CSS tokenazation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization)
- [Escaped characters in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#escaped-characters)